# Is there a way to do a dry run with Python requests.delete method?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm interacting with a REST API and would like to be able to test my method for deleting records without actually deleting anything. Is there a way for me to see what *would* have been deleted *had* I run the command, without actually running the command? So, for example,

```
def delete_entry(dry_run=True):
    if dry_run:
        return hypothetical_response
    else:
        response = requests.delete(url)
        return response
```

Comment: No. How would *requests* know what your *server* would have done? You should either mock the call, or implement the dry-run argument on your *server* side

Comment: I recommend checking out [requests-mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/) in order to 'pretend' how the server responds. This is good for testing your client code. If you have control over the server, it is often feasible to add a 'dry run' parameter that causes the response to declare what would have been done, which may also be your use case. If you clarify which you're after I can expand.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To clarify: I do not have control over the server. Thanks for the requests-mock recommendation, I'm looking into it now.